# How to download a list of the datas from angular to xls

Tags: html, angular, typescript, observable

I have a button that I show data which I need, but at the top of the page I have a button which I can download this data and I want to download in the Excel file.
For example

Name, Surname, Cost, Year
Test, Test, 1000, 2018

This is the code what I have writed but I dont have any data when I download.

```
<button (click)="downloadExport()">Download Export</button>

<div *ngFor="let valueItem of selectedValueItems">
   <app-planning-overview [valueItem]="valueItem"></app-planning-overview>
</div>


downloadExport() {
        this.valueItem$.subscribe(response => {
          const blob = new Blob([]);
          const date = new Date();
          const filename = 'planning-' + date.toLocaleDateString() + '_' + date.toLocaleTimeString() + '.xls';
          saveAs(blob, filename);
          console.log(blob); //This shows me size 0.
        });
      }
```

This is the aray to shown from the planning-overview

```
<div class="aggregateCostsName" style="font-size: 11px">
        {{valueItem.name}}
      </div>
```

But when I write something like this

```
 downloadExport() {
      const data = 'Q1, Q2, Q3';
      const blob = new Blob([data]);
      const date = new Date();
      const filename = 'planning-' + date.toLocaleDateString() + '_' + date.toLocaleTimeString() + '.xls';
      saveAs(blob, filename);
```

Then in the xls it is saved and Q1, Q2 and so are there but only the selected data are not

Comment: Please provide the `saveAs` method.

Comment: @Brianvdb I have added more code to see, but what do you mean to provide the saveAs method ?